# Redirecting query strings: mod_rewrite giving 404 error but tester showing (almost) correct

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a query string redirect to a more friendly url. This is within WordPress but I'm trying to do the mod_rewrite in the htaccess (am adding an extra rule, not touching any of the WordPress rules)

This is my desired url: localhost/site/events/term-1/term-2/term-3

And this is the actual url: localhost/site/events/?tax_1=term-1&tax_2=term-2&tax_3=term-3

Here is the code I have used:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /site/
  RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ events/?tax_1=$1&tax_2=$2&tax_3=$3 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>

... WordPress rules here ...
```

This is giving me a 404 error when I go here: localhost/site/events/term-1/term-2/term-3 (but I have checked and localhost/site/events/?tax_1=term-1&tax_2=term-2&tax_3=term-3 is going to the correct place). I'm not getting any errors in the apache error log.

When I tested the rule on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ I was getting this result from the above input:

http://localhost/site/event/%3Ftax_1=term-1%26tax_2=term-2%26tax_3=term-3

which seems like it may be an encoding issue, but all the research I have done into the encoding of these inputs and outputs, this seems unlikely, and I'm wondering if this may be an issue with the tester.

Can anyone point out where I may be going wrong? I've been scouring the docs for mod_rewrites and I feel like my rules are written correctly. Is it an apache setting maybe? Or a conflict with WordPress?

Thanks

EDIT
Adding a NE flag to the rule is now giving me the correct result in the tester, but I am still getting the 404 result on the actual server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't technically solved my problem, but by using WordPress rewrite rules instead of mod_rewrite I have got the desired features.

For anyone else looking this what I added to my functions file:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=PAGE_ID_OF_EVENTS_PAGE&tax_1=$matches[1]&tax_2=$matches[2]&tax_3=$matches[3]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%tax_1%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%tax_2%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%tax_3%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Instead of hooking into the permalink events/, it needs to be sent to the index.php with the specified post id of where the page is, as the other custom rewrites will not run first, so WordPress won't know what events/ means.

The first function adds the rewrite rule and hooks it into the initialisation. The third parameter specifies when the rule will be run in the list of rules running - it has to be top as if it is bottom it will not run.

The second one adds the query vars as tags so that WordPress is aware of the custom query variables.